# meteor run error in applying adminLte

Tags: meteor, admin

I've downloaded an entire meteor "admin lte" source from Github and put them all to the folder meteor created.
(script > https://github.com/meteor-factory/meteor-admin-lte)

However, it causes several errors in js files on running meteor.

here are my questions

1. where is the proper location entire script should be placed ?
2. Adding packages is not enough for applying jquery? if all the js files causing errors removed, meteor runs but many parts such as charts doesnt appear.

Answer (score -1):

I guess this is something you were looking for, please check out this link https://github.com/jtolla/meteor-admin-lte

**Instruction!**

Differential Boilerplate
AdminLTE 2
Installation

Clone this repo to

```
git clone https://github.com/jtolla/meteor-admin-lte.git <yourapp>
```

Remove .git

```
cd <yourapp> && rm -rf .git
```

Start coding!

Comment: While this link may answer the question, it is better to include the essential parts of the answer here and provide the link for reference.  Link-only answers can become invalid if the linked page changes. - [From Review](/review/low-quality-posts/11392142)

Comment: @Ethaan thanks! I have update the instruction to this one. If the repo removed, it is still the problem.